# Bash expansion in a while loop

Tags: bash

I am trying to run a bash command multiple times, using lines in a text file as parameters:

```
while read -r line;
do
        curl -X POST \
        -u JLCarveth \
        -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
        -H "Authorization: token [...]" \
        -H "Accept: application/json" \
        https://myurl.com/api/v1/user/repos \
        -d '{"name":"$line"}';
        printf "Done $line\n";
done < repo_names.txt
```

The problem is, the API is not receiving the `name` parameter. How do I go about properly substituting the `line` value as a JSON format?

Comment: Replace `'{"name":"$line"}'` with `"{\"name\":\"$line\"}"`. Variables don't expand inside single quotes.

Comment: Thank you! Sort-of related question: If I stop the script halfway through (using Ctrl+C), the script stops, but I can no longer clear the screen with Ctrl-L, nothing happens. Also no characters will display on terminal when I type, until I press `Enter`. Do you know why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

Use a tool like `jq` to ensure that correct JSON is generated, no matter the value of `line`.

```
while read -r line;
do
   curl -X POST \
    -u JLCarveth \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "Authorization: token [...]" \
    -H "Accept: application/json" \
    https://myurl.com/api/v1/user/repos \
    -d "$(jq -n --arg n "$line" '{name: $n}')"

    printf 'Done %s\n' "$line"
done < repo_names.txt
```